# High load average and freezing when using NVidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I'm constantly facing interface freezes (e.g. everything running very slow, sometimes even the mouse movements are lagging). I've checked the `htop` and it says that there's a very high load average (e.g. 8 to 12 on 2-core CPU). And a lot of applications are using CPU (50 to 80% CPU load), though I tried to kill all the apps that use CPU intensively and there were still interface lags.

I've read that this can be caused by NVidia drivers, so I've tried to install different versions of NVidia drivers via 'Additional Drivers' panel (I've tried using NVidia drivers versions 378, 381, 375, 340 and 304), but still there were freezes and interface lags. Only when I've installed Nouveau driver (xserver-xorg-video-nouveau), everything went okay and there were no interface lags.

So, my question is: how to set up NVidia drivers so there would be no interface lags (or is it even possible? I suppose so, because there are a lot of people using NVidia drivers instead of Nouveau and are fine with it)? I don't want to use Nouveau driver because this way I won't be able to use Bumblebee and Primus.

Xubuntu Studio 17.04 Zesty x64, NVidia GeForce GT630M.

(Probably it's a duplicate, though I didn't find the answer in any question related to NVidia drivers and interface freezes/lags).

Comment: This is obviously some bug in the binary NVidia driver. The fact that other peoples have no such problem is just saying that you hit some vague corner case. I see two possible ways out of the problem: α) keep trying different kernel, Xorg, DE, hoping to find when the effect disappears β) report a bug to NVidia *([there's a link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/790452/reporting-graphics-driver-bugs-/) about it, but they don't seem to like end-user reports as you can see in reply. In this case I'd start with a usual support, then if they won't help, switched to "devtalk" forum anyway)*.

Comment: You know, in general you could also try profiling, although that wouldn't be easy given it's reproducing randomly, and in *(userspace?)* driver. But if you'd succeed in this, it might give a hint where to look at.